# Laptop fan always on in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, ati, dell, overheating, fan

I have dual booted Ubuntu 12.10 with Windows 7 on my Dell Inspiron 15r 3rd gen laptop. In Windows I have absolutely no problem with fan. But when I boot into Ubuntu after about a min the fan speed starts increasing & about 5mins later the fan is at extremely high speed. This is resulting lots electricity being sucked by the AC Adapter because it becomes extremely hot.

I have ATI Radeon 7670m GPU. I dont know whether the CPU fan or the GPU fan is running. So I wanted to know whether it is possible to know the temperature of all the hardware like CPU, GPU, HDD, etc? So that I can understand which driver is having the problem.
Any other mechanism to debug the cause of problem would also be very helpful.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I use Jupiter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

After installing that, just open the application. Use Performance in the applicaton menu and set to Power saving and you should almost immediately hear the fan slowing (if your temperature sensors don't sense a high temperature).

It also allows you to disable some devices and set screen resolutions, monitor settings, etc.

Use lm-sensors to get an idea of the temperatures.

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect (say yes to all)
sudo sensors
```